# I want to generate thirty unique alphanumeric strings in PHP loop

Tags: php

```
<?php
// Set length of the string
$length = 30;
$random = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 15);
// Use for-loop to generate thirty unique alphanumeric strings
For($i=0; $i<$length;) {echo $random.$i++."<br />";
```

The code above generates something like 5523d651bfb642b0, 5523d651bfb642b1, 5523d651bfb642b2, 5523d651bfb642b3 etc. The next value is just too easily predictable. I want something totally different like when I refresh the page in the browser. If I remove loop and just echo $random, the page generates a totally different string every time I refresh the page. How do I generate something totally different like 5523d651bfb642b0, 2yyd00nngbh201km, 78gdfmpqg01597v etc using loop? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you're echoing the same string 30 times. You need to change `$random` in the loop. Also use `mt_rand` as it's more random.

Comment: @Charlotte: Your insight was of great help. I just had to do the code like this, and it worked perfectly well.
    <?php
    $length = 30;
    For ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $random = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 15);
    echo $random."<br />";
    }
    ?>
    
And I got thirty different strings as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function generateRandomString($length = 30) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$i = 0;
$times_to_run = 30;
while ($i++ < $times_to_run)
{
    generateRandomString();
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and it worked perfectly well too. I noticed that the result contain mostly alphabets. On two occasions, out of 30 results I spotted two(2) that were purely alphabets. Nothing of such happened with the corrected version of my code which uses md5. Its letters and numbers were rather evenly distributed. So I think I'll go for md5 instead.

Comment: The reason for that is the coefficient of letters to numbers. There are only 10 numbers to choose from and 52 alphabetical characters to choose from. You can reduce this number by only using lower or upper case letters.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 7, it's easy to generate a random string:

```
$bytes = random_bytes(5); //random. Increase input for more bytes
$code = bin2hex($bytes); // eg: 385e33f741
```

Before PHP 7, I would generate an alphanumeric code with a function

```
function getRandomString($length){
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';    
    $result = '';
    while(strlen($result)<$length) {
        $result .= $chars{mt_rand(0,strlen($chars)-1)};
    }
    return $result;
}
```

To get a 10-character random code, you just call:

```
$randomString = getRandomString(10);
```

You can add more characters to $chars ofcourse